# migrating a stored procedure from mysql 5.0 to 5.1.37

Tags: mysql

I am trying to migrate my database from MYSQL 5.1.37 on my machine to MYSQL 5.0 on my hosting company. But the problem is, while I am able to migrate my tables I got errors when I try stored procedures.

Here is one which works fine on my machine.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `db986`.`sp_addUser`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`tse`@`%` PROCEDURE  `db986`.`sp_addUser`(_loginid varchar(45),_password varchar(45),_email varchar(45),_accountcreateddate date,_gender char(8))
BEGIN
insert into login (`loginid`,`password`,`email`,`accountcreateddate`,`gender`) values (_loginid,_password,_email,_accountcreateddate,_gender);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am not sure what should I have to fix to get it running on the hosting company, I am using *1and1* as my hosting server.

Any help.

Comment: This should be tagged 'mysql', not 'php'. I don't know how to change tags.

Comment: yea, sorry. i have changed it now. Thanks.

Comment: You say you're getting an error, but you haven't told us what the error is.  Can you edit in the exact and full wording of the error message you're getting, along with when you're getting it, please?  (For example, are you getting it when you define the procedure, or when you call it?)

Comment: Thanks, the problem is when i want to create the procedure and the error is like this.

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `db986`.`sp_addUser`$$
CREATE' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the begin and end key from the code and works fine.  dont know why though.